# how to make code appear in the terminal ? terminal show also Build finished successfully, Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image]

It doesn't show me the code output. Should I change the setting or configure something ?

I tried edit task.json and reinstall VScode.

Comment: Building project and running project are two different things. From the image, you are just build your project. Where is the run part ?

Comment: You seem to only *build* the program, you never *run* it.

Comment: VSCode is not at all the same as Visual Studio, despite its bonkers name - please use a different tag. and this has nothing to do with c==

Comment: so what should i do to run it ?

Comment: What does [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs) tell you?

Comment: thank guy i think i figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Open New terminal from options above.
Command: g++ .\practice.cpp
it will create .exe file with some name in same folder
Command: .<file_name>.exe
This will run the file

To make it easy to run program
Install "Code runner" extension: It will give to button to run program on top-right.
By default, it will give output in Output tab in panel
Make few changes, in code runner setting by checking check boxes for
1)'clear previous output' and
2)'Run in terminal'
This will run the program in one click without needing to build and run with commands.

Comment: actually all i did was click on the run code and select run code. the problem was i select run C/C++ file.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot that you shared, to run it from a terminal:

```
cd /Users/seal/Desktop/projects/cpp
./practice
```

It seems that you only built the code, that's why it wasn't being executed:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/seal/Desktop/projects/cpp/practice.cpp -o /Users/seal/Desktop/projects/cpp/practice
```

This command will compile `practice.cpp` into the executable `practice`.

You only need to build again when the source code changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that when you were setting up minGW you copied the C:\MinGW\bin inside "Enviroment Variables" -> "User variables for " -> "Path" -> "New" instead of copying it in "Enviroment Variables" -> "System Variables" -> "Path" -> "New" section. I deleted the first one and put it inside System Variables and it worked for me.